# Prove with a partition and bijection that $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+4}{8}\rfloor+ \dots=n$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Using partitions and 1-1 correspondence of the set {1, 2, ... n}, prove that $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+4}{8}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+8}{16}\rfloor+ \dots=n$

Hint:

First, we look at a small case. Let n = 25. We discover that the formula works.

Now, we partition the set of positive integers from 1 to 25 according to the number of powers of 2 that divide them. Let $S_k$ be the set of positive integers from 1 to 25 that have exactly k factors of 2. We list the results in the following table:

$k$ is $0$ then $S_k$ is $\{1, 3, 5,...,25\}$ and $\#(S_k)$ is 13

$k$ is $1$ then $S_k$ is $\{2, 6, 10,...,22\}$ and $\#(S_k)$ is 6

$k$ is $2$ then $S_k$ is $\{4, 12, 20\}$ and $\#(S_k)$ is 3

$k$ is $3$ then $S_k$ is $\{8, 24\}$ and $\#(S_k)$ is 2

$k$ is $4$ then $S_k$ is $\{16\}$ and $\#(S_k)$ is 1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any attempts on the general problem?

Comment: You have the partition, and the bijection is just $\phi(k)=k$.  Strange question....